# When was a script executed?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In Unix/Linux is it possible to find out when a script was executed the last time?

e.g. say you have a script called `cleanup.sh` and you want to know when was the last time it was executed. How can you find out?

Comment: If the script doesn't log it and you can't tell from side-effects and you don't have process accounting (or something) logging general process running then no.

Comment: You could try to read it's `atime`, though I don't know whether that is actually set when running a script.

Comment: If nothing else has read or looked at the script, and the filesystem isn't mounted with `noatime`, you can run `stat yourscript` and look at the last access time.

Comment: @filmor, yes, atime is set when running (if the filesystem has it enabled at all) -- requires read, after all. OTOH, if there are forensics going on, chances are good that the file has been read by someone looking at it for other purposes.

Comment: That said -- is this a programming question, as opposed to a usage question?

Comment: (all that said -- because of the performance penalty associated with tracking access times, setting `noatime` in `/etc/fstab` by default is quite common).

Comment: According to this http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch21_05.htm there are systems that don't update `atime` for executables.

Comment: @filmor, yes, but scripts are by definition read by interpreters. Indeed, your link acknowledges that: "pure-executable file (not a shell script)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out by running stat on the file.

```
stat [filename] | grep Access
```

This should present you two lines. The second one would show you last date and time of execution.

If cleanup.sh is in your $PATH variable, this should be more specific:

```
stat `which cleanup.sh` | grep Access
```